# HTML being stripped or not working as it should

Tags: php, html

I have a website where users will enter chatrooms with HTML codes (depicting avatars and pictures, their names, sometimes links, etc) but since updating the server and php to 7.3 even with converting UTF-8 it all seems to work, except for quotes and ? marks in links and things like that breaking it seemingly being picked up as code or not reading it right? I feel like I am missing something simple that was changed.

An example below.

```
<center><font size=2><font color=#333333><font face=Verdana>....Name Here....
</font></font></font><br><img src=https://pics.randomwebsite.com/etc/etc/etc/etc/random.jpg>
<br><font color=#8c6647><font face=Verdana><b><a href=https://randomwebsite.com/index.php?act=Pages&pid=55 target=_new><font size=2>
<font color=#8c6647>...Name...</font></a></b><br>
<font color=#8c6647><font face=Verdana><font size=1>Random Saying and Quote<br>
<img src=https://randomwebsite.com/uploads/etc/random.gif title=Name>
<br>-</font></font></font><br><font color=#d7bba0><font face=Verdana><font size=2>
```

this is just one example with all " " stripped, ' ' stripped, because otherwise it will break it. This code works fine except for the ? in the link which is simply from an SMF forum. If I use a URL shortener for the link that removes the ? it works as it should.

---

### **EDIT**

To clarify, if I put quotes in there, it won't be displayed right at all, and it will change the codes they input to something random like

```
<font face=Verdana><b><a href=https://randomwebsite.com/index.php?act=Pages&pid=55 **rrrrget=_new**><font size=2>
```

or if I have the link in there like it is now with a question mark in it.

**I appreciate the clarification. To give more context to this, markup has been fixed and corrected on the pages. Users comes to the website, click on the name of a chatroom they would like to enter into, then enter in their desired name and enter into the rooms (displayed in an iframe chatbox top and bottom) (html is allowed to be entered here, here comes the issue)**

**When they do, this is displayed correctly, UNLESS, they have quotes, apostrophes, or links with question marks in it or try and use any kind of html "code" like target="_new"**

Comment: Side note: Don't use the `<center>` or `<font>` tags. They don't exist anymore and are obsolete

Comment: it's not clear to me what got broken. You shared an example that doesn't highlight that. Are you saying that your response is encoded with a charset the browser can't correctly deal with?

Comment: did you use `<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><meta charset="UTF-8">` on top of your html?

Comment: I have <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8"> at the top of each page of html where this is being input to be displayed

Comment: You use some pretty old mark-ups in your code like <b> and <font> this is has nothing to do with your question but I suggest updating them into divs or spans and using css for the fonts and boldness.

Answer (score 0):

The quotes are not removed by updating server or php. Look at the history of commands that you have executed on the server, it seems that you ran a command that removes the quotes from a directory, it is a possibility.